# Prevent SharePoint documents from download and print

Tags: sharepoint, documents, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am in a requirement wherein I do not want to allow user to print/download documents from SharePoint(Office365 to be precise). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Information Rights Management (IRM), IRM is a subset of Digital Rights Management (DRM), these technologies protect sensitive information from unauthorized access.

On Office 365 go to Admin tile. In the Admin Center choose Azure AD. In Active Directory go to the Rights Management Tab and activate the Rights Management.

In the SharePoint Admin center, choose "Settings" in the left navigation. Scroll till you see the relevant IRM. Choose "Use the IRM service specified in your configuration", then refresh the IRM settings. The IRM settings menu will appear in all the document libraries of your SharePoint Online sites.